# Horizontal Navigation Bar: How to center text and set colours

Tags: html, css, navbar

I am trying to create a horizontal navigation bar with the following properties:

1. The anchor text is centered horizontally and vertically in the list
   items.
2. The entire list item is a clickable link.
3. On hover, the background colour of the list item and the colour of the anchor text are swapped.

Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/schemer/s8aodoc0/) that manages to accomplish only #2. None of the solutions that I have found for #1 seem to work. #3 escapes me.

Advice is appreciated.

Here is the working code:

```css
#navbar ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  display: table;
}
    
#navbar li {
  display: table-cell;
  float: left;
  width: 200px;
  height: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #f0e68c;
}
    
#navbar li:hover {
  background-color: black;
}
    
#navbar li a {
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<div id="navbar">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#intro">Intro</a></li>
    <li><a href="#bio">Bio</a></li>
    <li><a href="#issues">Issues</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Please describe your problem in the question title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use below CSS to get all the 3 things you wanted.

```
    #navbar ul
    {
        list-style-type: none;
        display: table;
    }
    #navbar li{
        float: left;
        text-align: center;
    }

    #navbar li a
    {
        display: table-cell;
        width: 200px;
        height: 50px;
        text-decoration: none;
        color: black;
        vertical-align: middle;
        background-color: #f0e68c;
    }

    #navbar li a:hover{
        color: #f0e68c;
        background-color: black;
    }
```

I have used `vertical-align: middle` to align text it vertically and gave your `li` styling to `a` tag to achieve this.

Fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/MasoomS/6mn0fun4/1/

Answer (score 2):

You can use this css. Check this link https://jsfiddle.net/oynd1sq6/

```
#navbar li:hover a{
color:#ffffff;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this ... just changed ur css

```
ul {
list-style-type: none;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
overflow: hidden;
}

li {
float: left;
}

a:link, a:visited {
display: block;
width: 120px;
font-weight: bold;
color: #FFFFFF;
background-color: #98bf21;
text-align: center;
padding: 4px;
text-decoration: none;
text-transform: uppercase;
}

a:hover, a:active {
background-color: #7A991A;
}
```

https://fiddle.jshell.net/ofp184pn/1/

Answer (score 1):

Just two modification you need is.

> **To accomplish #1:**

Make line height of anchor same as line height of li tag. i.e. `50px`

> **To Accomplish #3**

Add style rule for anchor.

```
#navbar li:hover a{
    color:#f0e68c;
}
```

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/dlinx/wgchvgxe/) is fiddle

```css
#navbar ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  display: table;
}
#navbar li {
  float: left;
  width: 200px;
  height: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #f0e68c;
  ;
}
#navbar li:hover {
  background-color: black;
}
#navbar li a {
  display: inline-block;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
  line-height: 50px;
  /*Make the line height same as height of li tag*/
}
/*Add style for anchor*/

#navbar li:hover a {
  color: #f0e68c;
}
```

```html
<body>

  <div id="statement">

    <div id="navbar">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#intro">Intro</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#bio">Bio</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#issues">Issues</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>

  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Below Code is for html

```
<ul class="nav">
  <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="/about/">About</a></li>
  <li><a href="/work/">Work</a></li>
  <li><a href="/clients/">Clients</a></li>
  <li><a href="/contact/">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
```

Below code is for css

```
.nav{
    border:1px solid #ccc;
    border-width:1px 0;
    list-style:none;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    text-align:center;
}
.nav li{
    display:inline;
}
.nav a{
    display:inline-block;
    padding:10px;
}
```

Try this i hope it will work for you

Answer (score 0):

Only updated your code...

For color hover effect add:

```
#navbar li a:hover{
    color: #f0e68c;
    background-color: black;
}
```

And for horizontal align you should add "line-height" and "vertical-align" properties to your "#navbar li" selector:

```
#navbar li
{
    display: table-cell;
    float: left;
    width: 200px;
    height: 50px;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #f0e68c;
    line-height: 50px;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rvc59s12/)

Answer (score 0):

Your all 3 problems are solved.
Check it out

```
#navbar ul{
list-style-type: none;
float:left;
}

#navbar li{ width: 100px;
height: 50px;
text-align: center;
background-color: #f0e68c;
float:left;
}

#navbar li:hover{
background-color: black;
}

#navbar li a{
display: inline-block;
text-decoration: none;
height:100%;
color: black;
}

#navbar li a:before{ 
 height:100%;
 vertical-align:middle;
 content:'';
 display:inline-block;
 }
```